# sequelizejs relations/associations, hasMany/belongsTo vs reference on definition model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

im a little bit confusing about relations on sequelize.

Is the same to do:

```
var User = this.sequelize.define('user', {/* attributes */}), 
Company  = this.sequelize.define('company', {/* attributes */});

User.belongsTo(Company);
```

that do:

```
var User = this.sequelize.define('user', {
    company_id : {
        references: {
            model: 'Company'
            key: id
        }
    }
    /* more attributes */
}), 
Company  = this.sequelize.define('company', {/* attributes */});
```

what are the difference? apparently two codes do the same tables as result, where in user table is added companyId foreign key to Company.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They are just different methods to achieve the same result. Depending on the patterns you are following in your code or the specific options, one may end up being more clear than the other. Notice that in your example the former is much more compact than the latter, which might make it a better choice.

There is a bug in your example however. The first would indeed result in a foreign key of `companyId`, however in your second example you use `company_id`. If you want to use underscored table and column names instead of camel case, you will need to pass in the [`underscored: true`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model) option in `Sequelize.define()`.

Comment: thank you for response. I read about underscored and other options. When i user the second form to create composite primary key (with belongsToMany) the pk/fk key its the last attribute of my table, how can place the order of attributes?

Comment: I don't think that's possible currently (since it doesn't really matter that much), but the code is open if you wanted to add that feature :)

Comment: Thanks again. Adding the attributte to my model with reference option and in the referenced hablé use the classmethod with belongsToMany seems solve the attributte order problem.. can u tell me if is bad practice? Maybe litros bit rebundant..

Comment: I do not think they do the same. 
I think this is the proper answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305459/sequelize-model-references-vs-associations