# Sequelize JS - Which do I use? Model.key.references or 'Associations'?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, schema, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize. Current working on a small schema, needed to add a foreign key to a table, and found the following:

```
sequelize.define(
    "my_model", {
        "id": {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
        },

        ...

        "linked_model": {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,

            // Should I be using this form to create foreign keys?
            references: {
                model: MyOtherModel,
                key: id
            }
        }
    }
)
```

A little later, I found out about the associations API - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html - Which can also be used to create foreign keys on related tables:

```
const Player = this.sequelize.define('player', {/* attributes */});
const Team  = this.sequelize.define('team', {/* attributes */});

Player.belongsTo(Team); // Will add a teamId attribute to Player to hold the primary key value for Team
```

The same question also appears here - [Sequelize model references vs associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305459/sequelize-model-references-vs-associations)

Which of the two is considered best practice?

Comment: official example repo. of sequelize is better option for me. check here https://github.com/sequelize/express-example