# assotiating two tables in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, associations, sequelize.js

Im having problems associating 2 models. I will try to describe the problem as detailed as possible and hope you can help me.

I have 2 Models: Zone and PLZ (both are also tables in database-mysql).
There can be One Zone having many PLZs and one PLZ can belong to One zone.

On saving a zone with its PLZs I have a table called "zone_plz" with only two columns: zone_id and plz_id. Both have foreign keys to Zone.id and PLZ.id

Zone Model:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../util/database');
const PLZ = require('../models/PLZ');
const zone_plz = require('../models/relations/zone_plzs');


const Zone = sequelize.define('zone', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    color: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


module.exports = Zone;
```

PLZ model:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../util/database');
const Zone = require('../models/Zone');
const zone_plz = require('../models/relations/zone_plzs');


const PLZ = sequelize.define('plz', {
    plz: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    city: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    district: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }

});


module.exports = PLZ;
```

and this is the zone_plz model:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../util/database');
const PLZ = require('../../models/PLZ');
const Zone = require('../../models/Zone');


const zone_plz = sequelize.define('zone_plz', {
    zone_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Zone,
            key: 'id',
        }
    },
    plz_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: PLZ,
            key: 'id',
        }
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


module.exports = zone_plz;
```

and this is how I query it:

```js
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    zone_plz.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: PLZ,
            as: 'plz'
        },
            {
                model: Zone,
                as: 'zone'
            }]
    }).then((result) => {
        res.send({status: true, data: result})
    }).catch(function (err) {
        next(err)
    })
});
```

As you can see i want to return a zone with all the belonging plzs to the user.

Im new to sequelize and Im also not sure if this is the right approach. I get the error: **plz is not associated to zone_plz!**

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You created references, not associations. Please, first of all, read the differences: [Sequelize model references vs associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305459/sequelize-model-references-vs-associations)
then create associations between plz & zone like:

```
plz.belongsToMany(zone, {through: 'zone_plz'});
zone.belongsToMany(plz, {through: 'zone_plz'});
```

Comment: Im writing this in my zone_plz model but getting the error: PLZ.belongsToMany(Zone, {through: 'zone_plz'});
    ^

TypeError: PLZ.belongsToMany is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/transport/models/relations/zone_plzs.js:28:5)